# Laravel 8 - Illuminate\Auth\EloquentUserProvider::validateCredentials()

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-8

I have an application where I want to have authentication but not use User models. The model is called Karyawan. But when I change the auth.php it starts showing this error:

> Illuminate\Auth\EloquentUserProvider::validateCredentials(): Argument
> #1 ($user) must be of type Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable, App\Models\Karyawan given, called in
> C:\KKP\Project_KKP\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard.php
> on line 426

Laravel version is 8

**auth.php**

```
'defaults' => [
    'guard' => 'web',
    'passwords' => 'users',
],

'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
],

'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Models\Karyawan::class,
    ],
],

'passwords' => [
    'users' => [
        'provider' => 'users',
        'table' => 'password_resets',
        'expire' => 60,
        'throttle' => 60,
    ],
],
```

**App\Models\Karyawan.php**

```
namespace App\Models;

use App\Models\Cuti;
use App\Models\Role;
use App\Models\Divisi;
use App\Models\Jabatan;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;

class Karyawan extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $guarded = ['karyawan_id'];
    protected $table = 'karyawans';

    public function scopeSearch($query, array $searchs) {

        $query->when($searchs['search'] ?? false, function($query, $search) {
            return $query->where('nama', 'like', '%' . $search . '%')
            ->orWhere('divisi', 'like', '%' . $search . '%') 
            ->orWhere('jabatan', 'like', '%' . $search . '%')
            ->orWhere('agama', 'like', '%' . $search . '%')
            ->orWhere('nik', 'like', '%' . $search . '%'); 
        });
    }

    public function role_id()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Role::class);
    }

    public function divisi()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Divisi::class);
    }

    public function jabatan()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Jabatan::class);
    }

    public function cuti()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Cuti::class);
    }
}
```

**web.php**

```
Route::get('/', [BasicLoginController::class, 'login']);
Route::post('/', [BasicLoginController::class, 'authenticate']);
```

**BasicLoginController.php**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class BasicLoginController extends Controller
{

public function login()
{
    return view ('login.login', [
        'title' => 'Login'
    ]);
}

public function authenticate(Request $request) {
    $credentials = $request->validate([
        'email' => 'required|email:dns',
        'password' => 'required'
    ]);

    if(Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
        $request->session()->regenerate();
        return redirect()->intended('/dashboard');
    }

    return back()->with('loginError', 'Email atau Password salah');
}
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

as the error says, your class need to implement the interface `Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable` which the common user model do by extending the class `Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;`

So either implement the contract in your class and declare all needed method functionality in it.

**OR**

Just extend the existing `Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User`

```
namespace App\Models;

//...
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class Karyawan extends Authenticatable
{
```

The class `Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User` extends the model class `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model` so the model functionalities will still be available.

**EDIT:**

Here, copy paste this model and you should learn some [PSRs](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/) especially [PSR-4](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/)

```
namespace App\Models;

use App\Models\Cuti;
use App\Models\Role;
use App\Models\Divisi;
use App\Models\Jabatan;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class Karyawan extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $guarded = ['karyawan_id'];
    protected $table = 'karyawans';

    public function scopeSearch($query, array $searchs) {

        $query->when($searchs['search'] ?? false, function($query, $search) {
            return $query->where('nama', 'like', '%' . $search . '%')
            ->orWhere('divisi', 'like', '%' . $search . '%') 
            ->orWhere('jabatan', 'like', '%' . $search . '%')
            ->orWhere('agama', 'like', '%' . $search . '%')
            ->orWhere('nik', 'like', '%' . $search . '%'); 
        });
    }

    public function role_id()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Role::class);
    }

    public function divisi()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Divisi::class);
    }

    public function jabatan()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Jabatan::class);
    }

    public function cuti()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Cuti::class);
    }
}
```

Comment: okay, sir, I have progress.

I add to my Karyawan class:

`use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class Karyawan extends Model implements
    AuthenticatableContract,
    AuthorizableContract,
    CanResetPasswordContract
{
    use Authenticatable, Authorizable, CanResetPassword, MustVerifyEmail;
}`


but still have error:

Cannot use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable because the name is already in use

any suggestions @N69S ?

Comment: @GuztiEkaPutra You dont need to implement the contract and extend the 
`Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable`. just do one of them. hence the **OR** in my answer. But for future reference, if you have conflict in naming classes, then just change the aliases

Comment: I am so sorry, still dont get it Sir. Could you help me please to rewrite the code I need to fix? 

Try both ways but still occuring an error - or still using User models to authenticate

Comment: @GuztiEkaPutra there you go

Comment: Sir, I have found another issue, could you help me again?

Comment: @GuztiEkaPutra you should open another independent question for it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244796/discussion-between-guzti-eka-putra-and-n69s).

Answer (score 1):

Class Karyawan needs to implement `Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatableclass` interface.
Or you can extend Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User in your  Karyawan  Class.